# Alternative to using Queue for return value in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

In python multiprocessing, is there something like Process.return_value() ? 
Why not and what are the alternatives? (besides using Queue)

Background:
Currently, my code is contains a number of functions f like this which operate on large sequences of data, which are numpy arrays (a, b)

```
b= f(a)

def f(a):
    # do some work here
    return b
```

I can parallelize each function like this:

```
plist=[]
for i in range(ncores):
    p= Process(target=f, args=(a[i::ncores]))
    p.start()
    plist.append(p)
```

This speeds up this part of the code by a factor ncores. The problem is getting the return value:

```
for i, p in enumerate(plist):
    p.join()
    b[i::ncores]= p.return_value()
```

I cant find a way to retrieve the return value through p. I don't see why it would not possible this way, since p can communicate with the process on the core.

Right now, I'm using a Queue to get the return value, but I find them a bit cumbersome to work with: I have to pass both the Queue and an identifier to each function and put both result and ID in the queue:

```
def f(a, Queue=Queue, ID=-1):
    # do some work here
    if ID==-1:
        # normal interface
        return b
    else:
        # parallel interface
        Queue.put([ID, b])
```

And then when I read out the queue I have to match the IDs back to the original array:

```
for i in range(ncores):
    ID, result= Queue.get()
    b[ID::ncores]= result
    plist[ID].join()
```

Is there a shorter way to achieve this?

I've tried passing a dictionary or list as keyword to store the result in, this works with threading, but not with multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

What is the return value?

If it is something simple like and array or a number, you can pass a shared memory container to the `Process` instance in which it can store its result. If we imagine you just want to sum an array across multiple processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Value
import ctypes as C
import numpy as np

def func(input,output):
    # do something with input                                                         
    # put the result in output                                                        
    output.value = input.sum()

def launch_processes(n):
    outputs = []
    jobs = []
    for ii in range(n):
        input = np.arange(ii)

        # here use a synchronised wrapper to store the result of the func run
        # This can be replaced with an Array instance if an array is returned
        output = Value(C.c_size_t) 

        job = Process(target=func,args=(input,output))
        outputs.append(output)
        jobs.append(job)
        job.start()

    for job in jobs:
        job.join()

    for output in outputs:
        print output.value

launch_processes(10)
```

A neater way to do the above would be encapsulate the job in a single object by subclassing Process:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Value
import ctypes as C
import numpy as np

class Job(Process):
    def __init__(self,input):
        super(Job,self).__init__()
        self.retval = Value(C.c_size_t)
        self.input = input

    def run(self):
        self.retval.value = self.input.sum()

def launch_processes(n):
    jobs = []
    for ii in range(n):
        job = Job(np.arange(ii))
        job.start()
        jobs.append(job)

    for job in jobs:
        job.join()
        print job.retval.value

launch_processes(10)
```